# Sprite-Kit Began Touch Error

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

Im trying to create a method that when I touch a sprite named StartSprite Through my touchesbegan function it will print out something in my console. But for some reason when I click on the sprite nothing happens. This is my code.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

let StartSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "startLabel")



override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let borderRect = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0 , width: 400, height: 725)


    let welcomeLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "welcome");
    welcomeLabel.text = "Welcome";
    welcomeLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    welcomeLabel.fontSize = 65
    welcomeLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2 + 150)
    self.addChild(welcomeLabel)

   //StartLabel


    let rectangleBorder = SKShapeNode(rect: borderRect)
    rectangleBorder.position = CGPoint(x: 315, y: 25)
    rectangleBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.addChild(rectangleBorder)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()



    StartSprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    self.addChild(StartSprite)


    println("Hello")

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if touchLocation == StartSprite.position{

            println("Touches")

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code requires that you touch exactly the one pixel at `StartSprite.position`.

Try this instead:

```
let p = StartSprite.convertPoint(touchLocation, fromNode: self)
if StartSprite.containsPoint(p) {
    print("touched StartSprite")
}
```

If you're going to add more buttons, you might want to do this instead:

```
let target = nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
if target == StartSprite {
    print("touched StartSprite"
}
// check other buttons here
```

Comment: `nodeAtPoint` does not return an optional